# How to write Instagram explore layout with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to write this similar layout to Instagram explore with CSS Flexbox:

[image: My image layout]

and it's my code:

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 330px;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.bigger {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="box bigger"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

As you can see in this code, the next element does not fill the empty space in front of the big element.
What is the solution?

Comment: Have you considered a container with two small divs in column layout and place it alongside the bigger div?

Comment: Quick question, do you absolutely have to use flexbox?, this scenario looks like a good place to use `grid`

Comment: Hopefully the answer submitted by me fulfils your query of "Is it possible using `flex`?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.bigger:after` to display a container. Give it `position: absolute` and determine where to position it, which in this case was `left: 233px`.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 330px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.bigger {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
}

.bigger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 233px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box bigger"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

This answers your question of 'is it possible?', but this isn't something you should build on. The best way would be to either have a container with small divs in column layout beside the bigger div, or simply use `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a masonry layout: something that CSS flexbox can't handle using the DOM structure you have. CSS grid can do that. You can use the `dense` keyword in `grid-auto-flow` to ensure that CSS grid attempts to pack its children as densely as possible.

And of course, you need to use the relevant CSS grid properties to make things work:

- `grid-gap: 10px` is used to replace the `margin: 5px`
- `grid-auto-flow: row dense` is used to pack cells as densely as possible from one row to another
- `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` simply defines 3 equal-width columns. If you want to be explicit, you can also use `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);`, which allows you to leave out an explicit width on the parent
- `grid-auto-rows: 100px;` informs CSS grid that each row should be 100px tall

```css
section {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}
.bigger {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="box bigger"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: It explicitly says if it's possible to do with Flex-Box

Comment: @RodolfoRodriguez Where does it say so? OP simply asks if the intended layout is achievable using CSS: without specifying any specs. Learn how to read a question before you downvote next time.

Comment: "@Parco I want to know is it possible to do it with flexbox or no."

Comment: @RodolfoRodriguez I understood what he meant and I edited question To be useful..